# Resize image using jquery without using any server side script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am working for creating application of samsung tizen tv.
In my application, I display images from live URL. 
In one screen there are lot of images (aprrox. 150) and each image higher in size(approx. 1 MB) and higher in resolution(1920 by 1080).
Due to image size and resolution navigation between items becomes slow.
So I want to reduce image size using jquery. 
Is it possible to download image from url and physically resize image using jquery without using any server side script ?

Comment: When you say size, do you mean the image dimensions (or) file size?

Comment: yes i mean file size not dimension

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible in apps for samsung tv, but in browser you can achive this using canvas (in the example below, the size of the original image (baseImg) gets decreased twice)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var baseImg = $('#base')[0],
        outImg = $('#result-image'),
        canvas, context;

    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    // set canvas size to the size of original image
    canvas.width = baseImg.width;
    canvas.height = baseImg.height;
    context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
    context.drawImage( baseImg, 0, 0, baseImg.width / 2,  baseImg.height / 2 );

    outImg.attr('src', canvas.toDataURL() );
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4jfhyxv/1/)

And one more example that doesn't use jQuery and displays only resized image and doesn't display original image

```
<img id="result-image" />

var baseImg = new Image(), 
        outImg = document.getElementById('result-image'),
        canvas, context;

     baseImg.onload = function() {
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // set canvas size to the size of original image
      canvas.width = baseImg.width;
      canvas.height = baseImg.height;
      context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
      context.drawImage( baseImg, 0, 0, baseImg.width / 2,  baseImg.height / 2 );

      outImg.src = canvas.toDataURL();
     };

     // not requires in your case,it just allows to use toDataURL() for image loaded from another domain
     baseImg.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

     baseImg.src = "https://pp.vk.me/c626925/v626925429/26d09/KaotJEBjASw.jpg";
```

[check on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh3784nt/)

Comment: Can you elaborate your code? What is  $( '#base' ) and '.resize1' here ?